# How to get access to request inside custom class in django

Tags: python, django

customclass.py

```
class MyCustomClass():
    def __init__(self):
       if request.user.is_authenticated:
            // do somtehing


custom_class = MyCustomClass()
```

Hi

A have an issue to get request data on "**init**". How to get it there?

Comment: couldn't you just pass the value of the request object in the creation of `__init__`?

Answer (score 1):

write this:

```
class MyCustomClass:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
    
    def do_something_method(self):
        if self.request.is_authenticated:
            // do something


custom_class = MyCustomClass(request)
custom_class.do_something_method()
```

Comment: in that case I need to initialise MyCustomClass inside some "def"?

Comment: yes you have to do it in one of your views